# How to set ISO date format in IIS

Tags: iis, iso

I have a website and deployed it on IIS 10.0. It is always showing the date format as MM/DD/YYYY. But I want to display the date as ISO format i.e. YYYY-MM-DD. I don't want to hard code it in the code and want to set it from IIS. I heard about IIS .NetGlobalization settings. But I have no idea which UI culture displays ISO format.

Regards,

Sriram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use globalization web.config setting to achieve your requirement to modify culture to EN-CA. The en-ca date formate is 
YYYY-MM-DD.

Notice: This setting only work for asp.net application.

```
 <system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="en-CA" culture="en-CA" />
  </system.web>
```

Result:

[image]